# What is the difference between Yoghurt and Curd

Tags: indian-cuisine, yogurt

They taste almost same. Are they different?

Comment: I feel I'm on the receiving end of a cross-cultural dialect issue :) What geographic location is this relevant to?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A curd is a transitional element obtained, once milk starts to coagulate, the other being a water substance called whey. These are separated and cheese can later be made from the curd, via the addition of other ingredients, such as rennet. Or in the case of cottage cheese and paneer, an acid.

Yoghurt is a finished product, produced by by heating milk, then adding a live 'starter' culture. It's then kept at a stable warm temperature for a number of hours, followed by cooling.

Comment: This answer is relevant to the USA. In many other countries, what USA calls "yogurt" is referred to as "curd". (e.g. India. and, I am guessing UK)

Comment: @joyjit "Yoghurt" would be the UK term; Curds would either be the solids used to make cheese from, or fruit curds which are dairy free (made from egg yolks, sugar, citrus juice)

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes, 'curd' is what its called on the sub-continent.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said, they almost taste the same, but aren't exactly the same. Both are fermented dairy milk, but the level of fermentation varies for both.
Boiled and semi- warm milk is mixed with fermentation bacteria and allowed to set in a matter of 3-4 hours. This is yogurt. It is not sour, bu you can scoop and enjoy it.

Once this yogurt is kept aside in a warm place for more time, it curdles even more and that is when you get curd. It is more sour than yogurt. Hope this helps!

Comment: Welcome to Seasoned Advice.  **;-)** Could you please [edit] your answer and specify that what you're talking about is **[localised to South East Asia (including India?)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dahi_(Curd))**

Comment: Hi. Do you have any reference for your 1st paragraph? (3-4 hours thing)